# CUDA program that emulates a kind of cellular automata slower on the GPU than on the CPU

Tags: performance, beginner, c, cuda, cellular-automata

I'm a very new to CUDA, so I'm still trying to understand how to make the best use of the GPU. I've ported a C algorithm to it. This algorithm works by loading the memory with an initial input, then calling a `rewrite` function, which rewrites 128 bits of memory, consecutively, until we arrive at an answer. Since `rewrite` is completely local, it is easy to parallelize, because you can call it at the same time in different memory positions.

This is how I tested it for the CPU:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test_inputs.cu"
#include "rewriter.cu"

void process(int *mem, int len, int j){
    for (int i=j; i<len-2; i+=3)
        rewrite(mem+i*4, mem+i*4+4, mem+i*4+8);
};

int main(){
    // Loads initial input
    for (int i=0; i < memory_ints; ++i)
        memory[i] = i < program_nodes*4 ? program[i] : 0;

    // Prints it for visualization
    print(memory, 40);

    // Calls rewrite sequentially until the computation is done
    for (int k=0; k<clocks*3; ++k)
        for (int j=0; j<3; ++j) // for alternating alignments
            process(memory, memory_nodes, j);

    // Print the result (should have only 4 numbers)
    print(memory, 40);
}
```

This is how I tested it for the GPU:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test_inputs.cu"
#include "rewriter.cu"

__global__ void process(int *mem, int len, int j){
    int i = (blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x)*3 + j;
    if (i >= len-2) return;
    rewrite(mem+i*4, mem+i*4+4, mem+i*4+8);
};

int main(){

    // Loads initial input
    for (int i=0; i < memory_ints; ++i)
        memory[i] = i < program_nodes*4 ? program[i] : 0;

    // Prints it for visualization
    print(memory, 40);

    // Puts it on the GPU
    int *device_memory;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&device_memory, sizeof memory);
    cudaMemcpy(device_memory, memory, memory_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    // Calls rewrite in parallel until the computation is done
    dim3 block_size(16, 1);
    dim3 grid_size(memory_nodes / block_size.x / 3, 1);
    for (int k=0; k<clocks; ++k)
        for (int j=0; j<3; ++j) // for alternating alignments
            process<<<block_size, grid_size>>>(device_memory, memory_nodes, j);

    // Gets data back from GPU
    cudaMemcpy(memory, device_memory, memory_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(device_memory);

    // Print the result (should have only 4 numbers)
    print(memory, 40);
}
```

Unfortunately, the parallel version is about 2 times slower than the sequential version. `rewriter.cu` and `test_inputs.cu` are on [this repository](https://github.com/MaiaVictor/cuda_rewrite_tests). I'm aware this must be ridden of newbie mistakes, but that's why I'm asking here. What are the worst mistakes I made and how can I improve it?